# How to connect prism.js to textarea

Tags: syntax-highlighting

This code works fine:

```
<head>
    <script src='.../prism/prism.js'></script>
    <link href='../prism/prism.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<pre>
    <cоde class="language-html">
        <span>one</span>
    </cоde>
</pre>
```

But if you connect to the textarea, then nothing works.

```
<textarea name="text" class="language-html">
    <span>one</span>
</textarea>
```

Why? And what should be corrected that would work?

Answer (score 10):

PrismJs specifies that it uses the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags only, so a `<textarea>` won't work.

> Therefore, it only works with `<code>` elements, since marking up code without a `<code>` element is semantically invalid.
>   https://prismjs.com/index.html

However, there is a side project called PrismJs live which you can attach to textareas https://live.prismjs.com/ - It is made by [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/), and currently a work in progress.

The full and up to date instructions are on the website, however basically you need to include `prismjs-live.js` after `prism.js`, and `prism-live.css` after your standard, `prism`.css`.

With the Javascript library call, you also need to include the langauges you want to load too, e.g., `prismjs-live.js?load=php,javascript`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prism Live: Lightweight, extensible, powerful web-based code editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./prism.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./prism-live.css">

    <textarea aria-label="Enter your response here" rows="5" class="prism-live"></textarea>

   <script src="./prism.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="./prism-live.js?load=python,javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Great inspiration. I managed to do something similar with no added JS, but had to give up on horizontal scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by just overlaying a `<pre>/<code>` block over a `<textarea>` and mirrored what's in the `<textarea>`. Something like this. It's really the CSS that's doing the heavy lifting here, so you may want to tweak the styles to suit your needs. The key is just to match the `<textarea>` styles up to the `<code>` styles, so the caret stays in the right position.

HTML:

```
<div class='code-editor>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <pre><code></code></pre>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var editor = document.querySelector(".code-editor textarea"),
    visualizer = document.querySelector(".code-editor code");

editor.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
   visualizer.innerHTML = e.target.value;
   Prism.highlightAll();
})
```

CSS:

```
.code-editor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: monospace;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px;
    background-color: #f5f2f0; // default prismjs theme background color
}

.code-editor textarea {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    caret-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

.code-editor code {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Concept works sweet. Though i'm overriding `code` css to `white-space: normal !important; word-break: break-word !important;` so the code wraps as I type in `textarea`. Works sweet until I return a line break in `textarea` value, which then renders the prism code without the line break. Did you have this problem? I'm not using line numbers as this is even problematic with this problem. See screenshot... https://i.imgur.com/k1nJucM.png